# Matplotlib is plotting non-existent data in google colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, statsmodels

I am running the seasonal decomposition tool from statsmodels on a large time series. The decomposition tool is returning arrays full of nan's, yet matplotlib is able to plot the non-existent data.

When I print or attempt to otherwise manipulate the trend or residual component arrays of the timeseries, no values get returned. But matplotlib is able to plot the data. Can someone explain what is going on?

code is below, following by an image of the block after being executed:

```
csvfile=('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/NWI_project/Savitzky-Golay_filter.csv')
smoothed_values = np.loadtxt(csvfile, delimiter=',')

decomp = seasonal_decompose(smoothed_values, period=168, model='additive')
trend = decomp.trend
seasonal = decomp.seasonal
residual = decomp.resid
observed = decomp.observed

print("trend is", trend)
print("seasonal is",seasonal)
print("residual is",residual)
print("observed",observed)

plt.plot(smoothed_values, label='Original Data', color='blue')
plt.plot(trend, label='trend', color='red')
plt.plot(seasonal, label='seasonal', color='green')
plt.plot(residual, label='residual', color='orange')
#plt.plot(observed, label='observed', color='yellow')

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 5))

#plt.grid(True)
plt.show()`
```

Image of the results: [code block from google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiarE.jpg)

restarting colab has done nothing, as I continue to get the same results every time.

Comment: Are you sure that `trend`and `residual` are full of NaNs and not just the first and last values?

Comment: printing the arrays show it's full of NaNs.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the notebook and seeing if it still plots data?

Comment: `print` might be showing you only the start and end of the arrays. There could be valid values in-between. Running something like `np.nansum(decomp.seasonal)` would confirm whether it has valid values.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. I left the project and took a long weekend away. It now works properly and I cannot explain why. Maybe a glitch?

Answer (score 0):

I left the project and took a long weekend, upon returning I found For reasons unknown; the data is now there when I use the print function in Python. I cannot explain how or why, only that it now functions.

Comment: This should be a Comment or an Edit to the original question, not an answer.